iOS Notification Issue with Custom Alarm Using ‘Awesome Notification’ in Flutter
I wrote code in Flutter using awesome_notifications with the category set to NotificationCategory.Alarm. On Android, the notification works as expected, and the “STOP” button is displayed correctly. However, when running the same code on iOS, the notification appears, but it behaves like a push notification: the system alarm sound plays once, and the notification disappears. I want the alert to remain visible until the “STOP” button is clicked, and I want the custom sound I set to play, but that doesn’t happen. I’m not sure if the issue is with the sound settings or if the category is not correctly applied on iOS.
await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(

      actionButtons: [
        NotificationActionButton(
          //actionType: awesome_notifications.ActionType.KeepOnTop,
          enabled: true,
          key: 'STOP_ACTION',
          label: 'STOP',
          actionType: ActionType.Default,
          autoDismissible: false,
          color: Colors.black87,
          showInCompactView: false,
          isDangerousOption: true,
          //requireInputText: true,

        ),
      ],

      content: NotificationContent(

        category: NotificationCategory.Alarm,

        fullScreenIntent: true,
        //actionType: ActionType.KeepOnTop,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        id: subId,
        channelKey: "alarm_Category",
        title: DateFormat('yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm').format(schedule.date),
        //title: schedule.date.toString(),
        body: 'Alarm Memo: ${schedule.enteredText}',

        payload: {
          'subId': subId.toString(),
          'enteredText': schedule.enteredText,
        
        },

        
        displayOnForeground: true,
        displayOnBackground: true,
        autoDismissible: false,
        locked: true,
        icon: 'resource://drawable/ic_launcher',
        customSound: 'notification_sound.wav',
        showWhen: true,
        wakeUpScreen: true,
        criticalAlert: true,


      ),
      schedule: NotificationCalendar(

        repeats: false,
        preciseAlarm: true,
        year: notificationTime.year,
        month: notificationTime.month,
        //weekday: notificationTime.weekday,
        day: notificationTime.day,
        hour: notificationTime.hour,
        minute: notificationTime.minute,
        //second: notificationTime.second,
        //millisecond: notificationTime.millisecond,
      ),
    );


wesomeNotifications().initialize(
      'resource://drawable/ic_launcher',
      [
        NotificationChannel(
          channelKey: "alarm_Category",
          channelName: "alarm_Category",
          channelDescription: 'Notification tests as alerts',
          defaultColor: Colors.blue,
          ledColor: Colors.white,
          playSound: true,
          onlyAlertOnce: false,
          importance: NotificationImportance.Max,
          soundSource: 'notification_sound.wav',
          criticalAlerts: true,
          enableVibration: true,
          enableLights: true,
          ledOnMs: 1000,
          ledOffMs: 500,
          locked: true,

        ),
      ],
    );


The NotificationCategory.category field is only effective on Android. iOS notifications cannot act how you describe. They are simply delivered and then disappear into the notification stack.

Thank you for the response. How can I make the notification stay visible on iOS or have the alarm sound play as expected? Currently, it behaves like a push notification, playing once and then disappearing. Could it be that the custom sound I set isn’t properly connected? Or is there a different setting required for alarm notifications on iOS?

There is no "alarm" notification on iOS. iOS notifications make the sound and then either disappear or remain on screen depending whether the user has selected "temporary" or "persistent" banner style in the settings for your app.  If your custom sound is longer than 30 seconds, iOS will play the default sound instead.
